# babel french + compilation issue

Tags: compiling, babel, polyglossia

Since yesterday I'm using polyglossia for one of my documents. Today I opened another document in which I use babel and that worked just fine yesterday morning. Suddenly I can't compile it anymore :

```
Message :    
échec de la commance pdflatex.exe-syntex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "bresil".tex
```

If I use polyglossia instead of babel it's working. Can you tell me what's the problem? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{letter}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[french]{babel}       
%\usepackage{polyglossia}    
%\setmainlanguage{french}       
\usepackage{textcomp}    
\usepackage{ifpdf}    
\ifpdf    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    
\else      
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}\fi        
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsfonts}    
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{makeidx}    
\usepackage{graphicx}     
\pagestyle{empty}    
\usepackage[scale=0.775]{geometry}     
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}    
\addtolength{\parskip}{6pt}     
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
```

Comment: Is there some other error or warning messages before this lines ? Did you try to erase the .aux file and compile again ?